# UIScrollView Not Showing All Content Even After Making Size of Scrollview (10,000 , 10,000)

Tags: xcode, uiscrollview, scroll

thanks for reading. I am making a UiScrollView to show content. For some reason I am unable to scroll to the bottom of the UIScrollView to see all content. No matter what I change my [scroller setContentSize:CGSizeMake(x,x)]; to, it makes no difference... 1,1 or 10,000 , 10,000 nothing changes. Here is my code. Thanks for the help.

```
 @interface ViewController : UIViewController {

UIScrollView *scroller;


 }

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scroller;
```

and the .m file

@synthesize scroller, testScroll;

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
 {
      [super viewDidLoad];
[scroller setScrollEnabled:YES];
[scroller setContentSize:CGSizeMake(400,2000)];


 }
```

And my scrollview's size is (331, 1875)

Thanks a lot

Comment: the testscroll in the synthesize section is now gone, all the outlets are also linked up correctly too :c

Comment: Maybe your scrollView is bigger than your view? Check that in storyboard.

Comment: Why is your scroll view size 1875 in height? This is larger than any ios device can display. (1024 in height for a portrait iPad). So you might miss that area because it doesn't fit on screen.

Comment: I need it to be that large to fit all my content on

Comment: I changed the size of the scrollview itself in the storyboard (so the size was 320,320 but the content was 420,2000), but I still cannot scroll to the bottom of the content when in the simulator.

Comment: Anyone at all? Still absolutely stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

myScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 500);

Do not forget to set scroll view delegate.